# transition with css3

Tags: html, css, animation, hyperlink, transition

Does anybody know how to algin a line under my text automatically to all? 
[**here is my animation**](http://jsfiddle.net/DashDesign/SD58Z/430/)

```
<div class="line"><div>behance.net</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="line"><div>google.pl</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="line"><div>twitter.com</div>
</div></br>
```

CSS

```
.line{
    font-family:Tahoma;
    width:0px;
    position: absolute;
    background:black;
    transition:width 0.4s ease ;
}

div:hover{
    position: absolute;
    width:86px;
}
.line div{
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
    bottom:1px;
}
```

In the first example, everything works fine, the width of line is ok, but in other no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution with less markup:

## [**demo**](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/Ffpdx)

```
<div class='line'>behance.net</div><br>
<div class='line'>google.pl</div><br>
<div class='line'>twitter.com</div><br>
```

CSS:

```
.line {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-position: -85px 0;
  transition: 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.line:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, crimson 1px, transparent 1px) no-repeat;
  background-position: inherit;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  color: transparent;
  content: '';
}
.line:hover { background-position: 0 0; }
```

---

#### ***Note***:

*My demo uses [**-prefix-free**](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) which adds prefixes as needed. WebKit browsers still need prefixes for [**transitions**](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions) and [**gradients**](http://caniuse.com/css-gradients). You'll have to add these yourself in your code. When you do, please remember to **always** put the **unprefixed** ones **last**!*

Comment: What do you mean? Works perfectly for me? I've added a link to the live demo.

Comment: Ok, now is great, but, when the titles are longer, the problem appear again. Like above.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to change the value for `background-position`. From `-85px` to `-285px` or a minus value that's at least as big as the `width` of your biggest title.

Comment: Right, in the case of larger text is a small delay, but this is a trifle. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SD58Z/431/)

***HTML***

```
<div class="line">behance.net <span></span></div> <br />
<div class="line">google.pl <span></span></div> <br />
<div class="line">twitter.com <span></span></div> <br />
```

***CSS***

```
.line {
    font: 400 1em Tahoma;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px 0;
    position: relative;
}

.line span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -90px;
    bottom: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #c00;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s;
}

.line:hover span {
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I found one problem with that. When te titles are longer, the problem reappears.